# making children processes wait for another for loop

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

i've been making google searches about my question for 2 days but im done with it. I have very basic information about process management, fork etc. I've been told to create some children processes of a same parent process and send them seeds by using pipes so they can produce some random numbers, all for their own. But I'm stuck at creating children processes.

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++) {
    /* TODO: spawn the processes that simulate the players */
    switch(pid = fork()){
        case -1:  // ERROR
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0:  // CHILD PROCESS
            printf("My parent id is %d \n", getppid());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default: // PARENT PROCESS
            wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

When I go with this code, parent creates `NUM_PLAYERS` children but I can't seem to use them in another for loop since they had terminated at the end of the case 0. When I just remove `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` line, so many processes are created and they have all different parents. So my question is, how to properly create children processes and use them later?

Answer (score 3):

If you remove `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` your child will continue executing where it was forked, IE it will go back to the close brace of the `for()` loop, and generate new children itself. What do you want the child to do? You should make it do that, and then do `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` and not let it return to to the `for()` loop.

Note also that `wait()` will only wait for one process to quit.

Comment: I need to send it some seeds through a pipe and by calling a function called `void shooter(int id, int seed_fd_rd, int score_fd_wr)`, so i think i need to make them wait for other for loop. But I don't know how to make them wait and access them at another for loop below the current for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
void do_something()
{
    //create random numbers or whatnot
}
```

//...........

```
case 0:  // CHILD PROCESS
    printf("My parent id is %d \n", getppid());
    do_something();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

You'll need the parent to `wait` on the children in a later loop.  The way you have it will block until a single child returns.  You want to create multiple children before then `wait`ing on them.

Note that you still have to add the pipe logic so parent/child can communicate.

**EDIT**

This is the broad outline of what you need to do:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++) {
    /* TODO: spawn the processes that simulate the players */
    switch(pid = fork()){
        case -1:  // ERROR
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0:  // CHILD PROCESS
            printf("My parent id is %d \n", getppid());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

// only the parent will ever execute below here

for (i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++) 
{
    while ( /* read each child's pipe*/)
    {
        //do something with data
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++) 
    wait(NULL);

return(0);
```

Comment: I actually don't have an idea how to do that. Should I remove             `wait(NULL);` and place it in another loop?